# WordPress is not sending the 2nd email in the same request

Tags: errors, wp-mail

When I try to send more than one email message in the same request, only de 1st message is sent, the rest of the messages are blocked with the error "Message body empty".

The following code should send 4 different emails, each one with different subject and message, but only the first one is sent:

```
$to = "email@example.com";
$subject = "Mail test ";
$message = "This is the body ";

wp_mail($to, $subject . "1", $message . "1"); // Sent
wp_mail($to, $subject . "2", $message . "2"); // Not sent (Message body empty)
wp_mail($to, $subject . "3", $message . "3"); // Not sent (Message body empty)
wp_mail($to, $subject . "4", $message . "4"); // Not sent (Message body empty)
```

I'm using **WordPress 5.6.2** and **WP Mail SMTP 2.6.0**

**Edit:** (Solved) I checked the other plugins and the issue was caused by an outdated "Email Templates" plugin. Once I updated it to the last version, I started receiving all the messages.

Comment: Your exact code works fine for me. Have you actually tested with this code? Or do you just have _similar_ code that doesn't work?

Comment: I tested this exact code before to post it here. Do you use WP Mail SMTP?

Comment: No. So if it works without the plugin then the issue is the plugin, or your configuration of it. Since third party plugins are off topic here, you'll need to speak with its author.

Comment: I added the same question in the plugin's support page: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-is-not-sending-the-2nd-email-in-the-same-request/

Comment: I checked the other plugins and the issue was caused by an outdated "Email Templates" plugin. Once I updated it to the last version, I started receiving all the messages.

Comment: @juankvillegas please post the solution as a solution, don't edit it into your question. Remember this is a Question Anser site not a discussion forum thread, you need to post the answer using the big box underneath

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not caused by WordPress. It was caused by a plugin.

In this particular case, I checked the plugins installed looking for anything that could modify the mail behavior. I disabled the plugin "Email Templates" and started receiving all the messages normally. Then I noted that there was an update available for that plugin, I applied the update, tested again and it was working as expected.

So, in summary, the issue was caused by an outdated plugin.